# How to store non-serializable java object in Redis

Tags: java, redis

I wanted to store java objects as values in Redis. As far as I know, we can store only bytes in Redis. The java objects I use are from third party jar and does not implement serializable. Does Redis solve this use case? If so how can we achieve it?

Comment: You will probably have to write your own serialization function or user [replaceObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#replaceObject-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: If it's feasible, I recommend using JSON instead of Java serialization. Not only is it actually faster, but it also avoids compatibility problems and is easier to debug.